# Crystal Reports 11 - How to wrap the entire report, its on landscape but too wide

Tags: dynamic, landscape, column-width, crystal-reports-2011

I need to create a C11 report that can be run on a dynamic date range that is passed in. However, the landscape page setup is still not wide enough to fit all the months in a year. The months are headers along the top and each has the same four columns of data rows that are pulled in underneath, for many records. Is there a way to wrap the whole report? I attempted to create a second details and grouping sections, but C11 wouldn't let me have independent details/grouping from what already exists...

The following link is close to what I'm talking about:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481

However, I need to retain my headers. Example:

(page header)......January...     Feb....    March ....  April....    May ....   June .....  July..... (I run out of space)

(details sec)...availbility...reserved....ownerres.....etc...

(Group Footer) ... shared values......shared values......shared values....etc...

(Page footer)... shared totals......shared totals......shared totals....etc..

Comment: Ah. crystal reports... where the positioning and wrapping are made up, and your desires are irrelevant.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Now It should @NicolasMoise